# Grails Domain With "First" and "Last" Properties

Tags: grails

I recently inherited a Grails code base with a domain class called `Name` with (among others), the properties `first` and `last` to represent the first and last parts of a name, respectively.  When writing a unit test which utilized this domain, I ran into some problems stemming from the names of these properties being the same as the [first](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/first.html) and [last](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/last.html) methods within Grails.  Now, I can fix the problems by renaming the properties, but I was wondering if there is a way within Grails to use the property names `first` and `last`.

Namely, the error I was receiving was `No signature of method: com.example.Name.first() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: first(), first(java.lang.String), first(java.util.Map), list(), list(java.util.Map), print(java.lang.Object)` when Grails attempts to apply a `nullable: true` constraint to the properties.

Here's the source of `Name`:

```
class Name {
    String first
    String middle
    String last
    static belongsTo = [person : Person]

    static constraints = {
        first(nullable:true)
        middle(nullable:true)
        last(nullable:true)
    }

    public static Name findOrCreate(String first, String middle, String last){
        def name
        name = Name.createCriteria().get{
            and{
                eq('first', first)
                eq('middle', middle)
                eq('last', last)
            }
        if(!name){
            name = new Name()
            name.first = first
            name.middle = middle
            name.last = last
        }       
        return name
    }

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }

}
```

Comment: You should be using `name.first` to get the first name of a `Name` instance. Why should it clash with `Name.first()` in any way?

Comment: In the constraints block, when Grails attempts to apply `first(nullable:true)`, the exception noted above is thrown.

Comment: Your `findOrCreate` method is functionally identical to this method that's added by GORM to all domain classes http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrCreateWhere.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say that this error happens in the constraints block. In that case you may be able to get it working with an explicit `delegate.`, i.e.

```
static constraints = {
  delegate.first(nullable:true)
  // and similarly for last
}
```

to force the `first` to be treated as a call into the constraints DSL rather than to the static GORM method.

Comment: @RandomMooCow it's a useful trick to be aware of any time you have a name clash with a DSL. I often use this when writing XML with a MarkupBuilder if I want to create an element with the same name as a local variable.